# logging detailed information to file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, debugging, sql-server-2008, file

Does anyone have some code to simply log some detailed information to a file within a SQL query (or stored procedure or trigger)?  I'm not looking for anything fancy.  All I want to do is to quickly put debug information into my SQL, much like folks do for JavaScript debugging using alerts.  I looked at using Lumigent, but that seems like overkill for what I want to do.  I don't care what the format of the logging is in.  Below is a simple example of what I'd like to do.

Example:

```
DECLARE @x int;
SET @x = '123'
-- log the value of @x
```

============

## 9/6/2011 @ 4:01pm update

I tried the sqlcmd below, which works well.  But it doesn't work well when there are 100 parameters on a stored procedure when I want to debug.  In that case, I need to go put a break-point in my client code, then get the value of each argument. Then go and type out the exec command, and then look at the output file.  All I want to do is put one simple line of code into my SQL (perhaps calling another stored procedure if it takes more than one line of code), that writes a variable value to a file.  That's it.  I'm just using this for debugging purposes.

Comment: Your best bet is probably CLR, though it's not a 5-minute job.

Comment: what does CLR stand for?

Comment: Common Language Runtime - it lets you write procedures/functions in your favorite .NET language (C#/VB etc) and gives you much more power over features only in .NET or outside of SQL Server (such as file system access). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: Wow, I'm quite familiar with the CLR execution engine, IL instructions, and compilers in general (in fact in the last week).  Haha!  I'm actually reading "Compiling for the .NET Common Language Runtime" book right now.  :-).  So you confused me for a minute.. thought it was a different acronym.  But I had no idea you could do this in SQL!  I'll have to make some time to learn this!!  I'll up-vote you.

Comment: Why does it have to be a file? If this is just during debugging, can't you just as easily log to a table, and when you want to see the recent results, `SELECT TOP n * FROM logTable ORDER BY DateCreated DESC;`? This seems like much less hassle than using an archaic file-based log approach. You're already using a database, take advantage!

Comment: My MacGyver skills are fading.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with more background I think I can promote my comment to an answer:

Why does it have to be a file? If this is just during debugging, can't you just as easily log to a table, and when you want to see the recent results:

```
SELECT TOP (n) module, parameters, etc. 
    FROM logTable 
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC;
```

You can simplify the logging or at least make it easier to replicate from procedure to procedure by having a stored procedure that takes various arguments such as `@@PROCID` and others to centralize the logging. See [this article I wrote](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) for some ideas there - it's geared to just logging once per stored procedure call but you could certainly call it as often as you like inside any stored procedure.

This seems like much less hassle than using an archaic file-based log approach. You're already using a database, take advantage!

If you're committed to using a file for whatever reason (it might help to understand or counter if you enumerate those reasons), then the next best choice would likely be CLR, as already mentioned. A complete solution in this case might be beyond the scope of this single question, but there are tons of examples online.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you are in the middle of a transaction and it abends, your log is automatically rolled back and you cant see the messages.

Comment: @neves you can either (a) log the parameters etc. before starting the transaction or (b) log them to a `@table` variable first, which will outlive any rolled back transaction.

Answer (score 2):

One pretty easy method is to use either [OSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to run your procedure. These are command-line methods for executing SQL commands/procedures/scripts.

With those utilities you can pipe the output (what would normally appear in the "Messages" tab in SSMS) to a text file.

If you do this, in your example the code would be:

```
DECLARE @x int;
SET @x = '123'
PRINT @x
```

If you are running the same procedure multiple times, you can just save it a a one-line batch file to make it very easy to test.

Comment: I am able to see the PRINT command when I run it manually.. but writing it to a file is what I haven't gotten to work yet.  If you know the setup, please share.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver - just use `OSQL` from a command line: `osql -E -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -q "EXIT(exec dbo.MyStoredProc)" -o C:\Logs\MyOutputFile.txt`

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver explanation of the command line paramters are in the links I put in the answer.

Comment: This is neat, I'll up-vote you for helping ...  sqlcmd -S "dev-sql-02" -d "lims_dev" -U "sa" -P "password_for_sa" -Q "exec procPreAccessioningSave 'E12345', 54321, 7528, 4252" -o "C:\Users\MacGyver\Desktop\Logs\SQL_Log.csv" .... but this is identical to the results window in SSMS.  So it doesn't quite answer my question.  I am simply looking for SQL code that writes a variable to a file.  Or is this a lot of work?

Comment: I'll update my question to make it clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: To output directly from SQL to a file will likely require some .NET and not be simple